Is it possible to render MJML template with the MarkupTemplateEngine in a Groovy script?
I am trying to use the MarkupTemplateEngine to render a template in MJML but after trying for a while I am starting to doubt if it is possible. Is it possible or not ? If yes, I would like to have an example that works to test with.
So far what I did :
import groovy.text.markup.*

String mjmlTemplate = '''
mjml {
    mj-head {
        mj-title('Hello World')
        mj-preview('This is a preview text')
    }
    mj-body {
        mj-section {
            mj-column {
                mj-text('Hello World from MJML')
            }
        }
    }
}
'''

TemplateConfiguration config = new TemplateConfiguration();
MarkupTemplateEngine engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config);

def template = engine.createTemplate(mjmlTemplate)
def renderedMJML = template.make().toString()

println renderedMJML

the error I got :

Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method minus() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method minus() on null object
        at GeneratedMarkupTemplate0$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(GeneratedMarkupTemplate0:4)
        at GeneratedMarkupTemplate0$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(GeneratedMarkupTemplate0)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at GeneratedMarkupTemplate0$_run_closure1.doCall(GeneratedMarkupTemplate0:3)
        at GeneratedMarkupTemplate0$_run_closure1.doCall(GeneratedMarkupTemplate0)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at GeneratedMarkupTemplate0.run(GeneratedMarkupTemplate0:2)
        at test.run(test.groovy:30)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)

If I test with rendering HTML it works fine.

The "template" is just Groovy code (it is function calls with closures
and maps basically).  So you have to write the "methods" in a way,
Groovy can parse and call them.  So mj-body parses to mj.minus(body)
in a sense, hence the error.  You can use quotes for the
method-names/tags though.  E.g.
import groovy.text.markup.*

String mjmlTemplate = '''
mjml {
    'mj-head' {
        'mj-title'('Hello World')
        'mj-preview'('This is a preview text')
    }
    'mj-body' {
        'mj-section' {
            'mj-column' {
                'mj-text'('Hello World from MJML')
            }
        }
    }
}
'''

TemplateConfiguration config = new TemplateConfiguration();
MarkupTemplateEngine engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config);

def template = engine.createTemplate(mjmlTemplate)
def renderedMJML = template.make().toString()

println renderedMJML


this worked for me, thank you! I have another question, because I am still new to this. The main reason I want to use MarkupTemplateEngine is to be able to handle dynamic data in my MJML template. For example, if I want to pass a variable for title instead of 'Hello World' , how can I do it ??

Pass a model to make(); see https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_creation_of_a_template_engine
